# Delete recurring calendar item with PHP EWS?

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

The past couple of days I have been learning to use the [PHP-EWS class](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki) for reading/updating/deleting calendar entries. I have been able to create single events, read all calendar events for a day and remove events. My problem is that I cannot find any information in regards to deleting an entire series of recurring events. When I delete an event the code I have only deletes the entry of 1 event and not all instances of the recurrence.

Not sure if I am just passing the wrong Id and ChangeKey to the delete code or if there is special code to handle recurring events.

My code for deleting events is as follows:

```
<?php
// Define the delete item class
$request = new EWSType_DeleteItemType();
// Send to trash can, or use EWSType_DisposalType::HARD_DELETE instead to bypass the bin directly
$request->DeleteType = EWSType_DisposalType::MOVE_TO_DELETED_ITEMS;
$request->SendMeetingCancellations = EWSType_CalendarItemCreateOrDeleteOperationType::SEND_ONLY_TO_ALL;

$items = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
foreach ($IDs as $id) {
// Set the item to be deleted
    $item = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
    $item->Id = $id['Id'];
    $item->ChangeKey = $id['ChangeKey'];
    $items->ItemId[] = $item;
}
$request->ItemIds = $items;
// Send the request
$response = $this->ews->DeleteItem($request);
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have created a class to handle most of my EWS commands. Here is a function I created to handle getting the master event IDs.

```
public function GetMasterEventID($EventID)
{
    if (empty($EventID)) {
        return false;
    }


    $types = array('GetItemType', 'ItemQueryTraversalType', 'ItemResponseShapeType',
                   'DefaultShapeNamesType', 'NonEmptyArrayOfPathsToElementType', 'PathToUnindexedFieldType', 
                   'NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType', 'RecurringMasterItemIdType');
    $this->LoadTypes($types);


    $request = new EWSType_GetItemType();
    $request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;
    $request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
    $request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ID_ONLY;

    $properties = array('item:Subject', 'item:Categories', 'item:DateTimeCreated',
                        'item:LastModifiedTime', 'item:Sensitivity', 'item:ItemClass',
                        'calendar:Start', 'calendar:End', 'calendar:CalendarItemType',
                        'calendar:IsRecurring', 'calendar:Recurrence', 'calendar:FirstOccurrence',
                        'calendar:LastOccurrence', 'calendar:ModifiedOccurrences', 'calendar:DeletedOccurrences');
    $request->ItemShape->AdditionalProperties = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfPathsToElementType();
    foreach ($properties as $p) {
        $entry = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType();
        $entry->FieldURI = $p;
        $request->ItemShape->AdditionalProperties->FieldURI[] = $entry;
    }

    $request->ItemIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
    $request->ItemIds->RecurringMasterItemId = new EWSType_RecurringMasterItemIdType();
    $request->ItemIds->RecurringMasterItemId->OccurrenceId = $EventID;

    $response = $this->ews->GetItem($request);
    return $response;
}
```

The LoadTypes() function just loops through the EWSType files that are required and then includes them so I don't have to load every type file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to find the ID of the master appointment of the recurring series, then delete that master.

I don't 'do' PHP, but these are the actual SOAP calls doing the trick. Maybe they help you back on track:

Get recurring master ID (and some data) from an occurrence:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:GetItem>
         <mes:ItemShape>
            <typ:BaseShape>IdOnly</typ:BaseShape>
            <typ:AdditionalProperties>
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" /> 
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeCreated" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:LastModifiedTime" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Sensitivity" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemClass" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:CalendarItemType" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:IsRecurring" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Recurrence" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:FirstOccurrence" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:LastOccurrence" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:ModifiedOccurrences" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:DeletedOccurrences" />
            </typ:AdditionalProperties>
         </mes:ItemShape>
         <mes:ItemIds>
            <typ:RecurringMasterItemId OccurrenceId="AAMkADkyZT[snip]kgAAEA=="/>
         </mes:ItemIds>
      </mes:GetItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Delete item:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
      <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
      <typ:TimeZoneContext>
        <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
      </typ:TimeZoneContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:DeleteItem DeleteType="HardDelete" SendMeetingCancellations="SendToNone">
         <mes:ItemIds>
            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level-->
            <typ:ItemId Id="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgAB57O2JwAAAA=="/>
            <!--typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="?" InstanceIndex="?"/>
            <typ:RecurringMasterItemId OccurrenceId="?"/-->
         </mes:ItemIds>
      </mes:DeleteItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. You have gotten me back on track. After doing a lot more searching and seeing other posts you have made on this same subject I am cooking with gas!